# How to ensure that a Xamarin Forms app (AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback mode) is suspended correctly by iOS to prevent battery drain?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app running in AVAudioSessionCategory = Playback mode and it works very nice, background audio is playing and even my timers keep running in the background, which is fine during playback.

How can I ensure that after a user has decided to stop playing audio (either by pressing a button inside of the app or by pressing the pause button on the lock screen) my app will go into a Suspended state and it won't drain the battery?

Is there a way to either force my app to go suspended or a way to verify whether it has?

As a side-note: Hooking the OnSleep method in App.xaml.cs is NOT sufficient because it is being called every time the app goes to the background even if it's playing audio, my timers are running, HTTP calls working, etc.

**UPDATE**:

Made an interesting discovery today:

- Timers keep running running in the background when the app is started from Visual Studio in debug mode (over WiFi).
- Timers seem to get suspended automatically by the OS (iOS) when the app enters background in Release mode.

My conclusion is: maybe the entire problem lies somewhere in the 'framework' that is added to the app by Xamarin to ensure communication between Visual Studio and the app? (Console, breakpoints, etc.) It would be a logical explanation.

Comment: Hi, if make it stop playing , it will prevent battery drain more or less. I'm not undersrtanding the correct way you said.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, my goal is to make sure that my app is sleeping (and not consuming any battery life) when in the background. I made an interesting discovery though, adding it as an edit to my original post right now.

Comment: Hi, if the app enter into background, Timers will continue to work. You will need to stop it manually to make sure it stops. You couold have a try with [Application Does Not Run in Background Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/registering-applications-to-run-in-background#application-does-not-run-in-background-property) to check whether all threads stop.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, can you please tell me more how can I use this option to check whether all threads stopped? I definitely want to do it the right way. Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to set not allowed running in background from the shared document. Second, refer to [lifecycle of iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo) to stop all the threads or timers on `DidEnterBackground1 method.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I am using BackgroundAudio in my app (in my description), therefore I need the app to run in the background IF background audio is playing. On the contrary, I need to suspend the app when not playing in the background. It is a Xamarin Forms app (see description) therefore I don't think timers should be managed by DidEnterBackground because that's iOS specific. IMO it should be controlled witihin the common project as the timers are also started in the common project as Device.StartTimer. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Okey, if it only plays audio in background, you only can pause it to play. There are no ways to do more things to stop the app.

Comment: The original question is still unsolved: how to make sure that a Xamarin Forms app is suspended correctly by iOS when the app is in the background and music is NOT playing. Still the same question. Sometimes the Xamarin Forms app goes to sleep but sometimes it doesn't and drains the phone's battery in a few hours. Timers seem to be stopped. I find it impossible to debug this :(